# Renderização JSF

Tags: java, jsf

Como faço para renderizar os componentes do `Richfaces`.

Tenho um `combobox` e quando eu clicar em um item dele quero que renderize o meu formulário de acordo com o meu item.

Exemplos por favor.

Comment: Olá johnatan, bem vindo ao Stack Overflow. Para que possamos auxiliá-lo por favor complete sua pergunta com mais detalhes. Um exemplo concreto e auto-contido com *snipets* de código relevantes da *view* e dos *managed beans* envolvidos é bem vindo. Da maneira que você formulou sua pergunta (que na verdade não é uma pergunta, é um pedido por exemplos) o contexto ficou muito amplo e é muito difícil elaborar uma resposta objetiva.

Comment: Coloque também o que você já tentou fazer, suas dificuldades e os resultados obtidos até então.

Answer (score 3):

Para atualizar a tela parcialmente, isto é, apenas um trecho dela, após uma ação via Ajax você pode usar o atributo `update` caso tenha um botão. Veja a [documentação do Richfaces sobre isso](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#Re-Rendering).

Exemplo:

```xml
<a4j:commandButton value="update" reRender="infoBlock"/>
...
<h:panelGrid id="infoBlock">
    ...
</h:panelGrid>
```

No caso de querer executar uma atualização após a seleção de um item da combo, isso é possível através da tag `<a4j:ajax>`. Veja um [exemplo oficial](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=ajax&sample=selectsUpdates&skin=blueSky):

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectsBean.currentType}" valueChangeListener="#{selectsBean.valueChanged}">
        <f:selectItems value="#{selectsBean.firstList}" />
        <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" render="second" execute="@this" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>
    <a4j:outputPanel id="second" layout="block">
        <h:selectOneMenu value="#{selectsBean.currentType}" rendered="#{not empty selectsBean.currentType}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{selectsBean.secondList}" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>
    </a4j:outputPanel>
</h:form>
```